# Suppress displaying of exit status of system function in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I'm running the following command to append timestamp to data:

```
cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 | gawk '{printf "%s,%s\n",system("gdate +%s"),$0; fflush(); }'
```

However it also prints the exit status of system function:

```
1487029247
0,332
1487029247
0,332
1487029247
0,332
1487029247
0,332
1487029247
0,332
1487029248
0,332
1487029248
0,331
1487029248
```

How do I hide the exit status?

A simple bash script for testing:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq 50)
do
    echo "Welcome $i times"
    sleep 1
done
```

To test new script, runs:

```
./script.sh | gawk '{printf "%s,%s\n",system("gdate +%s"),$0; fflush(); }'
```

Comment: You need to display `cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1421` without awk.  Also, I don't understand how the bash script is related to the program above.

Comment: cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 simply sends a number every seconds, through hardware. script.sh is an equivalent testing script.

Answer (score 1):

`system` returns the rc code, which is printed by `printf`.  You would better try

```
system("gdate +%s"); print($0)`
```

If you don't like the newline after `gdate` output, read this: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html#Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe

Comment: I tested this: `./script.sh | gawk '{system("gdate +%s%3N"); getline x; printf "%s,%s",x,$0;}' `, but getline is blocking thus no value is printed.

Comment: This which you tested would not work, why should it?

Comment: The code you wrote in your comment makes no sense at all.  I cannot understand what makes you think that it might work.

Comment: I was trying to use getline to avoid the new line.

Comment: @DzungNguyen That should be `gawk '{"date +%s%3N" | getline x; printf "%s, %s", x, $0}'`; `system` isn't used.

Answer (score 1):

To include output of a shell command with other awk output would be:

```
awk -v OFS=',' 'BEGIN{cmd="gdate +%s"} (cmd | getline line) > 0{print line, $0; close(cmd)}' /dev/cu.usbmodem1421
```

The above assumes `gdate +%s` does whatever you want it to do as written. See http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline for how/when to use getline.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem and could not find a simple enough solution. I found that wrapping the system call inside a formated print solved my issue. This relies on the automatic printing of the system call. So test before you use.

For your example, you also have to deal with the newline being printed by date. I found that downstream string manipulation inside the system call would not be very reproducible so I resorted to using a bash printf to delete that newline.

```
cat ${file} | awk '{printf( "", system(" printf `date +%s` ")); printf(",%s\n" , $1); fflush(); }'
```